# region title is not showing in Right to left application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have Apex Application Version 18.2 Using Right to Left direction as application is in Arabic Language . I have a Simple Region in all forms which is not showing its title in any case as i have tried lot of ways but i am unable to see the region title. I have set all templates of a region but still its not showing me the title.Here is the image which has just simple region control and its not showing the title of the region.

[image]

Comment: can you demonstrate your question on apex.oracle.com

Comment: also, can you add the region settings?